# require в Роутере

Tags: express

Доброго времени суток,

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно исключить дублирование записей типа:
var mysql = require('..somefolder/mysql') из отдельного файла роутера.js, ведь они уже указаны в app.js